# Decoding a response from Tequila by Kiwi

Tags: python, gzip

I need to get a response with a flights from my airport to my destination. And everything works great with one little detail - "data" in my response is empty.

RESPONSE:

```
 {'all_airlines': [],
 'all_stopover_airports': [],
 'connections': [],
 'currency': 'PLN',
 'currency_rate': 0.221264,
 'data': [],
 'del': 0,
 'fx_rate': 4.519483,
 'ref_tasks': [],
 'refresh': [],
 'search_id': '44c439e0-449b-af9a-bab9-b7ae8c72677e',
 'search_params': {'flyFrom_type': 'airport',
                   'seats': {'adults': 2,
                             'children': 0,
                             'infants': 0,
                             'passengers': 2},
                   'to_type': 'airport'},
 'sort_version': 0,
 'time': 1}
```

I'm doing this with Tequila by Kiwi API. And there is an "prerequisition": *"The responses are G-zipped and need to be unpacked (response header Content-Encoding: gzip)"*. I have no idea what does it mean but maybe this "data" in response isn't empty, just Zipped. How can I unzip this?

Comment: I dont think you'd get an empty list if there was actually data there. The http client should know how to deserialize the full response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you made your request with requests library then it should be decoded automatically

> The gzip and deflate transfer-encodings are automatically decoded for you.

[binary-response-content](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content)

Comment: Ok, so I should look for bug in other place. Thanks!